# Separate Full String into Firstname, Middle Initial and Lastname by column

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, worksheet-function, separator

Using Excel, how can I separate a full name string, eg:

```
    Juan I. Dela Cruz
    Jojo Rambo
    Unlce Sam
    Mary Ann J. San Jose
```

into output of 'Firstname','Middle Initial' and 'Lastname':

```
+----------+----------------+----------+
|Firstname | Middle Initial | Lastname |
+----------+----------------+----------+
|Juan      | I.             | Dela Cruz|
+----------+----------------+----------+
|Jojo      |                | Rambo    |
+----------+----------------+----------+
|Uncle     |                | Sam      |
+----------+----------------+----------+
|Mary Ann  | J.             | San Jose |
+----------+----------------+----------+
```

Comment: In general, the problem of parsing names isn't trivial. How would you, for example, determine first versus last name in, say, "Mary Ann Dela Cruz" or "Betty Van Der Werden"? If you can decide on what you want your decision method to be, then use a combination of functions `FIND`, `MID`, `LEFT`, and/or `RIGHT`.

Comment: Lastname can be determined after the character (period) "." then Firstname can be determined even it has 2 Sentence before the 2 character "Letter and Period"

Comment: That works if there's a middle initial. But what if there is no middle initial and, therefore, no period per the examples I showed in my last comment? Or more generally, if the name is `X Y Z` (assume these letters represent words) with no initials (no periods), how do you know if the first name is `X Y` and the last `Z`, or the first name is `X` and the last name `Y Z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firstname:  `=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-3),LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))`
In Middle Initial `=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1,2),"")`
In Lastname `=IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)-1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)))`

each copied down to suit may be a start (for the examples provided) but, for the reasons as mentioned by @lurker, this is not likely to be a comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 0):

Initial thought is to use *Text to Columns* under the Data tab, with space as your delimiter.  However the previous comment brings up a good point as to determining your names.

If you do not have many instances of names with several spaces, such as your Mary Ann J. San Jose example, then text to columns will work well - you can combine your outliers manually.

Answer (score 0):

After working on this for a couple of days, here is what I have come up with.  This works on Excel 2000 as well.  Seems to work well on a data set that I am using that is formatted as "Last Name", "First Name" "MI".

My Name Field is in Column B and my Formulas are in H, I, and J

Last Name

```
=LEFT(B2,SEARCH(",",B2)-1)
```

First Name

```
=IF(LEN(MID(B2,LEN(H2)+3,LEN(B2)-LEN(H2)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B2,LEN(H2)+3,LEN(B2)-LEN(H2))," ",""))>0,MID(B2,LEN(H2)+3,LEN(B2)-LEN(H2)-LEN(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","|",LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""))))))-3),MID(B2,LEN(H2)+3,LEN(B2)-LEN(H2)))
```

Middle Inital

```
=IF(RIGHT(B2,1)=".",MID(B2,LEN(H2)+LEN(I2)+3,1),MID(B2,LEN(H2)+LEN(I2)+4,1))
```

So far this has handled any data that I can throw at it.

Good luck